# Character Creation Date

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there any method of seeing when a specific character was created?

The best I got is looking at the ***`Level 10`*** Achievement in the Achievements panel/window.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't reinstalled, you can check the date on the following folder: %WoW-Directory%/WTF/Account/*accountname*/*realm_name*. That folder gets created when you first access a character on a given realm. If you've reinstalled or reformatted, that date will be the first access since then.

You could alternatively try http://www.warcraftrealms.com/ and look up your character name in the census data, but it's a long shot - the data is populated by a third-party addon and there's no guarantee the date there is accurate either.

Aside from these two methods and the Level 10 achievement as you describe, there does not appear to be a way to find out exactly when you made a character.

Comment: It's been a very long time since I last played WoW, but does the `/played` command tell you when the character was created?

Comment: @JonK It doesn't, sadly. `/played` will report your total aggregate time spent playing a character and total time spent at your current level, but doesn't reveal dates.

Comment: @Gauzy Thanks - I wasn't sure and wasn't prepared to spend money and time installing again just to check! I've got a gut feeling that there is a way to find out though, I just can't remember what it is... You could presumably find out (roughly) when you created your *first* character by looking at your account history on battle.net - the day you first subbed is likely the day you made your first character. Obviously doesn't apply to newer characters though.

Comment: after typing in `/played` I'm always depressed ._.

Comment: @JonK Checking the first payment date is a good one I hadn't thought of, but it would probably only be useful if you were trying to find out when you created your first character.

Comment: @Jutschge "Time you enjoy wasting, was not wasted." Attributed to John Lennon.

Comment: Note that if you delete a character and create a new one with the same name, the old directory never gets deleted.